# Python requirements.txt to set few packages installed from file:// whl file and rest by pypi

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, pip

Need a solution to install python packages which are mix of local .whl files and rest from public registry (pypi), with the help of requirements.txt or one single command

My Expectation

> requirements.txt

```
mako file://<path_to_whl file>
flask
six == 1.14.0
...
```

Note: **mako** package is installed from local file:// .whl file and flask is installed from pypi registry.

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Should install the packages in one go.

I don't want to install file:// whl files and other packages seperately rather looking for solution which does automatically in one go.

Comment: Hint: every line in `requirements.txt` is either a package name or an URL but not both. Choose either name or URL in `mako file://<path_to_whl file>`

Comment: @phd I m looking for any solution, that includes both entries - offline and online packages.

Comment: Either name (to install from PyPI) or `file://` URL (to install from a local wheel).

Answer (score 0):

You can do both.  The problem is you are specifying a name for the local wheel install.  Just specify the path so in your case just remove mako and use relative path the wheel already is the name.

```
./<path_to_whl file>
flask
six == 1.14.0
```